# How to find missing numbers from array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, numbers

I have a string with numbers like `"3 -1 0 5"`. I need to generate a string with missing numbers from first (sorted) array. First array sorted would be `[-1, 0, 3, 5]`, so missing numbers from given sequence are `[1, 2, 4]`.

I am trying to solve it in most compact way with modern JS, not just `split`, `parse`, `sort`, for `min..max` if `index -1` then `push`, you know.

Comment: What is the range of the number? min number and max number?

Comment: Please demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, wouldn't that be `sorted.min()` and `sorted.max()`

Comment: @AdamAzad No, `Math.min(...sorted)` and `Math.max(...sorted)`.

Comment: @Xufox, thanks for the correction

Comment: I've created a benchmark for all the solutions below. Refer it [here](https://jsperf.com/arr-missing-strings/1).

Answer (score 2):

After sorting the array of original string, you can loop over the minimum and maximum range, and find the missing items in between.

Having a pointer (`arrIndex`) helps solving this problem in `n` complexity (after sorting), and a single iteration over the array.

```js
let array = "3 -1 0 5".split(' ').map(Number);
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);

let missing = [];
let arrIndex = 0;

for (let i = array[0]; i < array[array.length - 1]; i++) {
  if (array[arrIndex] === i) {
    arrIndex++;
  } else {
    missing.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(missing.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method in combination with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *methods.*

```js
let array =  "3 -1 0 5 -3 7".split(' ').map(Number);
array.sort((a, b) => a-b);
missing = Array.from({length: array[array.length-1] - array[0] + 1}, 
                        (_, idx) => array[0] + idx)
               .filter(elem => !array.includes(elem));
console.log(missing);
```

Comment: I’d link to `Array.from` rather than `map`.

Comment: sort sorts stringed values, not numbers without cb.

Comment: @AlexandrZavalny, i updated my answer and it's working perfectly

Comment: This isn't work when you have array like [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]. When in this case the program need to print - 2, 3, 4 ,5 6

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the sorting if you just want the missing numbers as you can use `Math.min(...arr)` and `Math.max(...arr)` for the loop condition and get the missing numbers.

```js
var str = "3 -1 0 5";

function getMissingNumber(str){
  var arr = str.split(/\s/);
  var missingNum = [];
  for(var i=Math.min(...arr); i<Math.max(...arr); i++){
     if(arr.indexOf(i.toString()) === -1){
       missingNum.push(i);
     }
  }
  return missingNum;
}
console.log(getMissingNumber(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split, map, sort, reduce and take a while loop for missing parts. Later join the missing parts.

```js
function getMissing(string) {
    return string
        .split(' ')
        .map(Number)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            var last = a[i - 1];
            if (!i) {
                return r;
            }
            while (++last !== v) {
                r.push(last);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(getMissing('3 -1 0 5'));
```

A bit shorter without `while` loop

```js
function getMissing(string) {
    return string
        .split(' ')
        .map(Number)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) =>
            (l => r.concat(Array.from({ length: v - l - 1 }, _ => ++l)))(a[i - 1]),
            []
        )
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(getMissing('3 -1 0 5'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMissing(str) {

    const sorted = str.split(' ').map(Number).sort((a,b) => a - b);

    const [min, max] = [sorted[0], sorted[sorted.length - 1]];

    const missingArr = Array.from({length:Math.abs(max-min)}, (_,i) => i + min).filter(item => sorted.indexOf(item) === - 1);

    return missingArr.join(' ');
}

const str = "3 -1 0 5"
const result = getMissing(str);

console.log(result);
```